# android backgorund looks good in hdpi, but mdpi and ldpi distorts it

Tags: android, background, distortion

I created some backgrounds for my application. These PNG pictures are 480x800 format and testing it on my phone (with hdpi res) or on the emulator in hdpi it looks very good. But if I test it in mdpi or ldpi, the backround distorts. Since 480x800 equals to 1:1.666, mdpi format is 320x480 with 1:1.5 and ldpi is 240x320 with 1:1.333, it is natural that the background will not fit all the size perfectly. I can change the backgrounds with sharedPreferences so I cannot use the layouts for this. I do not want to put more images into the app because it's already 3 megabytes (2 megabytes for the backgrounds). How should I solve this? Should I put all the beackgrounds into to app with smaller resolutions (120x200 for hdpi, 100x150 for mdpi...) and the screen will stretch it by itself?  I am afraid it would be blurred.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to use a 9-patch image instead. If that is possible for your background image of course.
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: These are drawings, I cannot use 9patch image.

Comment: You could add transparent a transparent border to your images to turn them into 9patch images.  (Effectively allowing the images to be centered/scaled on all resolutions).   How are you setting them as backgrounds?  Via a style or an ImageView?  If it's an imageview, you can specify the android:scaleType attribute.

Comment: If you really really want to use these background images, I think it is best to add them all to the package (so different resolutions) for better comfort for the user. I don't think that adding a transparent border to make 9patch images of these backgrounds will work actually, but I've not tested, maybe it does work. And the last idea: maybe you could try to minimize the app itself, so the reason why it is already 3MB. I think minimizing that could be a good idea too..